# how to create a new skill in twilio flex?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex, twilioflexwebchat

I'm trying to set up a webchat. I need to create different agents with different skills(eg: sales, marketing). I'm not able to find an option to create skills(and how to assign them to respective agents).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no UI for creating skills. They are arbitrary strings you attach to worker attributes. If you go to task router -> workers -> select a worker you'll see somethings like:

```
{
  "contact_uri": "client:joe_smith",
  "full_name": "Joe Smith",
  "image_url": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0078cd9b02fc2550990c9c5c8f261c22?d=mp",
  "email": "joe@example.com",
  "roles": ["admin"],
  "routing": { "skills": ["some_skill", "another_skill"] }
}
```

To add a skill add any string you want to the skills array in the worker attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Workers Skills direct by the Flex UI, accessing [https://flex.twilio.com/admin/ > Skills](https://flex.twilio.com/admin/skills) and then create your skills. After create, you can access the [https://flex.twilio.com/teams/ > Access Some Worker > Select the desired skills to attach it to the agent](https://flex.twilio.com/teams/).

I hope that it help you.

Comment: This is the easiest way to get started. You can see Twilio's tutorial here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/admin-guide/tutorials/skills-assignment